# How to change the last value of a row in .csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, arguments, argparse

I'm creating a to-do list using CLI and i want to change the last value of a row i.e. Status from 'Incomplete' to 'Complete'

I know that we can't edit a csv file just like that so what we have to do is read it change the value then overwrite the existing file. 
here's the csv file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fqc79mtVmZGZ_pb_2zrzDGVDmyMFWi6C
I tried this:

```py
import csv
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o', '--option', metavar='', help='-o <option> write either you want to add or view')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--select', metavar='', help='-l <used to select the task for modification')
args = parser.parse_args()


    def modify():
        select = args.select
        with open('csv.csv', 'r+', newline='') as file:
            lines = list(file)
            lines[int(select)][7] = 1
        with open('csv.csv', 'w+', newline='') as ifile:
            writer = csv.writer(ifile)
            writer.writerows(lines)
```

I want that when we run this:

```
python todoarg.py -o modify -l 2
```

it changes the status of 2nd row from 'Incomplete' to 'Complete'

Comment: What are you getting currently?

Comment: do you get error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: is this all your code ? why don't  you run function `modify()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, I looked at your csv and since you have a header line I think it may good to use your `S.No` as a unique taskid:

```
import pandas as pd
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o', '--option', metavar='', help='-o <option> write either you want to add or view')

# Here I added the action="append"
parser.add_argument('-l', '--select', metavar='', help='-l <used to select the task for modification', action="append")
args = parser.parse_args()


def modify(filename, taskids):
    taskids = list(map(int, taskids))  # just to change from str to int for your taskids
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";")
    df.loc[df["S.No"].isin(taskids), "Status"] = "complete"
    df.to_csv(filename, sep=";", index=False)

modify("csv.csv", args.select)
```

I'm using Pandas dataframe to make it easier. The `df.loc[...]` line is for selecting each row where S.No is one of your task id given in the command line and changing the Status column to "complete".

Also I made a little change that I think you can be interested in: I just added a small `action="append"` in your parser for the `select` option. This means you will be able to change multiple tasks at once by doing something like:

```
python todoarg.py -o modify -l 2 -l 6 -l 3
```

For your `option` parameter I can recommend you using the `choices` argument in the parser:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "-o", "--option",
    type    = str,
    choices = [
        "modify",
        "add",
        "cook_a_turkey"
    ],
    default = "modify",  # you can even use a default choice if the parameter is not given
    metavar = "",
    help    = "some help"
)
```

And for how to select which method to use based on the value given to the `option` parameter I don't think I have a good way to do this but maybe something like this can work:

```
my_methods = {
    "modify": modify,  # they keys are the same as provided in the choices in the argument parser
    "add": add_task,
    "cook_a_turkey": cook_that_turkey,
}
# And you can call the function like this: However you will have to change a bit your functions to parse the arguments in each of them.
my_methods[parser.option]("csv", args)

# For instance the modify will become:
def modify(filename, args):
    taskids = list(map(int, args.select))
    # ...
def add_task(filename, args):
    # do stuff
def cook_that_turkey(filename, args):
    # your grandma recipe
```

Comment: Thanks man, it was really helpful and all your suggestions were great, I'm new at python and all your suggestions helped me a lot but i wanted to see if there's a way to do this without using pandas?

Comment: I'm also getting `KeyError : 'S.No'` with this method

Comment: The KeyError means it did not find the `S.No` entry in the dictionary, here you should put the name of the column with your task ids in your CSV. Print the dataframe and look at the name of the columns.
Also, maybe change the `sep=`, I used a `;` because that's what I put in my tests but you should put the field separator of your CSV instead.

Comment: Thanks :)..I got that but still shows missing positional arguments filename and taskids what do i have to input in that?

Comment: Oh, right, for the very first example I gave, the filename should be `"csv.csv"` in your case and taskids should be `args.select`. But you will have to give them when calling the function, look at the last line of the 1st example (I'edited the filename to match your example).

Comment: Since you are a beginner, I'll explain just in case, when I created the function `modify(filename, taskids)` I created it with 2 arguments, `filename` and `taskids` those arguments are available to use ONLY inside this function. When I am calling this function `modify("csv.csv", args.select)` I give to it the two arguments in the same order: the value `csv.csv` will go into `filename` and the value of `args.select`will go into `taskids`.

Comment: oh okay. Now I get it. Thank you so much dude. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it without pandas too:

```
    def modify():
        with open("csv.csv", 'r+') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            f.seek(0)

            task = args.select

            for line in lines:
                if not task in line.split(',')[0]:
                    f.write(line)
            for line in lines:
                if task in line.split(',')[0]:
                    #what we do here is print existing values using their index
                    #with split function and adding 'Complete' instead of
                    #6th index which was 'Incomplete'
                    f.write('\n' + line.split(',')[0] + ',' + line.split(',')[1] + ',' + line.split(',')[2] + ','
                            + line.split(',')[3] + ',' + line.split(',')[4] + ','
                            + line.split(',')[5] + ',' + 'Complete')

            f.truncate()
```

I know this is a newb way but it works fine lol

Comment: Thanks mate :). Your suggestions were really helpful